# how to get sub value in array for ng-repeat option on angulars js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

use ng-repeat but can't get option value!

plz help!
html:

```
<ul ng-controller="app">
    <li ng-repeat="mainlist in mainlists">
    <p>{{mainlist.name}}</p>
    <select ng-options="mainlist.list for mainlist.list in mainlists.list">
      <option value="">{{mainlist.list.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this [demo](http://jsbin.com/udivop/2/)

js: just get  **{{mainlists.name}}** not get **{{mainlists.list.name}}**

```
function app($scope) {  
  $scope.mainlists = [
    {
      "name":"main001",
      "list":[
        {
          "no":"1",
          "name":"sub1"
        },{
          "no":"2",
          "name":"sub2"
        }]
     },
   {
      "name":"main002",
      "list":[
        {
          "no":"2-1",
          "name":"sub1"
        },{
          "no":"2-2",
          "name":"sub2"
        }]
     }]
 };
```

this [demo](http://jsbin.com/udivop/2/)

Comment: <select ng-model="list" ng-options="mainlist.list for mainlist in mainlists">
      <option value="">{{mainlist.list.name}}</option>
    </select>

use http://jsbin.com/udivop/4/edit 
but just get obj not value

Comment: You might like writing a directive for this.

Comment: thank you for your help , i need find more detail
some like http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive right?

Comment: What about {{mainlists.list[0].name}}? Or you have to nest another ng-repeat to print list elements

Comment: not get sub value option 2 , that's will be designation option 1 show

http://jsbin.com/udivop/6/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`ngOptions` directive requires a `ngModel` directive to be defined on select element.**

This is not a documented pitfall, but it is visible from the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.7/src/ng/directive/select.js#L192)

So, your selects will work if you add `ngModel` to them:

```html
<select 
  ng-model="mainlist.value" 
  ng-options="item as item.name for item in mainlists.list"
>
</select>
```

Or, if you were not planning to wire up the selects with a model (very unusual case), than you might want to use `ng-repeat` with your select options:

```html
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="item in mainlist.list">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: got it! http://jsbin.com/udivop/8/edit it's very useful,  i need to read more ,thx help